# Insert into table if it does not already exist

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, oop, model-view-controller

I have an application where users can add serial numbers(cells) to circuits.  I am attempting to modify the insert queries of two tables to check if the cell Id already exists.  If it doesn't I want to insert it but if it does exist I don't want a new record inserted.  I have searched and tried to apply what answers I found on SO that pertain to this, but have not had any success.

Here is my code starting with the
Controller

```
public function AddNewCell()
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            $circuitId = $_POST["circuitId"];
            $cellNum = filter_var($_POST["cellNum"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $toteId = $_POST["toteId"];
            $posId = $_POST["posId"];

            $stageCheckId = $this->GetStageIdByBatId($cellNum);
            if (empty($stageCheckId)) {
                echo json_encode("0");
            } else {
                $cellId = $this->form->InsertNewCell($circuitId, $stageCheckId, $toteId, $posId);
                $this->wk->InsertCell($circuitId, $cellId, $cellNum, $toteId, $posId);
                echo json_encode($cellId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Formation Model

```
public function InsertNewCell($circuitId, $stageCheckId, $toteId, $posId)
    {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_Cell_Tote_Track (Circuit_Id, Stage_Check_Id, Tote_Id, Position_Id) VALUES (:cid, :scid, :tid, :pid)");
        $this->db->bind(":cid", $circuitId);
        $this->db->bind(":scid", $stageCheckId);
        $this->db->bind(":tid", $toteId);
        $this->db->bind(":pid", $posId);
        $this->db->execute();

        $this->db->query("SELECT TOP(1) Cell_Id FROM tbl_Cell_Tote_Track ORDER BY Cell_Id DESC");
        return $this->db->single()->Cell_Id;
    }
```

Worksheet Model

```
public function InsertCell($circuitId, $cellId, $cellNum, $toteId, $posId)
    {
        $this->db->query("SELECT Circuit_Num FROM tbl_Circuit_Track WHERE Circuit_Id = :cid");
        $this->db->bind(":cid", $circuitId);
        $circuitNum = $this->db->single()->Circuit_Num;

        $position = $this->GetCellPos($toteId, $posId);

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_OCV_Worksheet (Cell_Id, Circuit_Id, Circuit_Num, Position_Num, Serial_Num) VALUES (:clid, :cirid, :cn, :pn, :cnum)");
        $this->db->bind(":clid", $cellId);
        $this->db->bind(":cirid", $circuitId);
        $this->db->bind(":cn", $circuitNum);
        $this->db->bind(":pn", $position);
        $this->db->bind(":cnum", $cellNum);
        $this->db->execute();
    }
```

I tried adding a unique constraint on the Cell_Id column of the tables by adding
`$this->db->query("ALTER TABLE tbl_Cell_Tote_Track ADD UNIQUE (Cell_Id);`
to the model functions but still received duplicates when a cell is entered with an existing serial number. I also tried

```
public function InsertNewCell($circuitId, $stageCheckId, $toteId, $posId)
{
     $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_Cell_Tote_Track (Circuit_Id, Stage_Check_Id, Tote_Id, Position_Id) SELECT $circuitId, $stageCheckId, $toteId, $posId
     WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT Cell_Id FROM tbl_Cell_Tote_Track)");
     $this->db->execute();
     $this->db->query("SELECT TOP(1) Cell_Id FROM tbl_Cell_Tote_Track ORDER BY Cell_Id DESC");
     return $this->db->single()->Cell_Id;
}
```

which appeared to prevent duplicates for that table but I was informed by a senior coworker that this was incorrect.  Apologies in advance as I am new to SQL and php.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if more code needs to be included.

Comment: perhaps `insert ignore into ...`  when used in conjunction with a suitable unique key?

Comment: A unique constraint at the database level is the _only_ way to guarantee you don't have duplicates. Never rely on select-before-insert mechanisms. If you were getting duplicates while you had a unique constraint defined, then go back and double check your syntax and your schema.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I thought I read that insert ignore was only available for MySQL and not SQL Server?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thank your for your response.  I am going back to check/correct my syntax and schema.

Comment: @torain20 - that could well be the case but there was no indication ( apart from the tags which I overlooked ) that this was specifically for MS SQL Server...

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius My apologies, you are correct.

Answer (score -2):

The last code (with select) could be choose if you set a `where` on a `select` statement, like

```php
"NOT EXISTS (SELECT Cell_Id FROM tbl_Cell_Tote_Track WHERE Cell_id = $cellId)"
```

And change the function argument sending the cell id.

If the `Cell_Id` is an autoincrement, then you need to define that constraint with a different columns.